# What are the core differences between MySQL WorkBench and SQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-workbench-j

I've searched substantially but I was unable to find a consistent answer for the following question: What are the core differences between "**My**SQL Workench/J" and "**SQL** WorkBench"? The only difference I've really found was that MySQL WorkBench is owned by Oracle.

Sorry if this is an inappropriate question.
Thanks.

Comment: They're completely different. MySQL workbench is specifically for MySQL, and written by the MySQL company, while SQL Workbench is a generic tool for multiple DBMS systems.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-workbench/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-workbench-j/info

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the links, but the one related with the sql-workbench has only two lines in it, and they aren't helping. But thanks.

Comment: [SQL Workbench home page](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Workbench/J has no relation whatsoever with MySQL Workbench.

SQL Workbench/J is DBMS independent SQL tool that works across a wide range of database products, not only MySQL. It's an open source project without any ties to Oracle.

The name SQL Workbench/J was chosen back in 2002 long before an Oracle product with the name MySQL Workbench existed - back then only [DbDesigner](http://fabforce.eu/dbdesigner4/) existed which was later forked into MySQL Workbench.

Probably the biggest difference is that SQL Workbench/J is a tool run SQL queries, whily MySQL Workbench is more of a ER modelling tool that over the years incorporated query capabilities as well.